# Где хранятся картинки из анонса инфоблока в битрикс?

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс

При переносе сайта на `битрикс` на другой хост. Из полей анонса в админки в инфоблоке пропали все картинки. Значение в массиве

`$arResult['PREVIEW_PICTURE'] = NULL`

Почему это происходит? где искать картинки. И где вообще в битриксе хранятся картинки из полей инфоблоков?

Comment: картинки хранятся в папке /upload не исключалась ли она из резервной копии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайдите в инфоблок и посмотрите загружена ли картинка в данном посте. Если нет, то загрузите и посмотрите появится ли она в массиве!
Далее зависит от того как вы получаете данные. Предположу что Вы используете метод `GetList()`. Пример:

`CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect);`

В  `$arSelect` указываете что хотите получить например `PREVIEW_PICTURE`:

`$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "DATE_CREATE","PREVIEW_PICTURE", "DETAIL_PICTURE", "PREVIEW_TEXT", "DETAIL_TEXT", "PROPERTY_*");`

далее пробегаете цикл данным способом:

```
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
        $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
        $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
//Код вывода
}
```

В `$arFields` хранятся Ваши `PREVIEW_PICTURE` и всё что Вы указали в `$arSelect`. Если там нет, то проверяйте правильно ли Вы указали id инфоблока в `$arFilter` и прикрепились ли файлы к посту!

Comment: если я добавляю в инфоблок картинку. Все работает,  в массиве появляется картинка. И на сайте тоже. , Вам спасибо.

Comment: @Dmitriy обращайтесь!